# How can i change a string that counts how many letters in a sentence into counting the occurence of one letter?

Tags: python, string

My task is to change this:

```
    sentence = 'The cat sat on the mat.'
    for letter in sentence:
    print(letter)
```

Into a code that counts the number of occurrences of the lowercase letter a.
I kind of get it but i don't know how to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use `count()`:

```
>>> sentence = 'The cat sat on the mat.'
>>> sentence.count('a')
3
```

Though, if you are required to use a loop:

```
sentence = 'The cat sat on the mat.'
c = 0
for letter in sentence:
    if letter == 'a':
        c += 1
print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using regular expressions:

```
 import re

 sentence = 'The cat sat on the mat.'
 m = re.findall('a', sentence)
 print len(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
occurrences = {}
sentence = 'The cat sat on the mat.'
for letter in sentence:
    occurrences[letter] = occurrences.get(letter, 0) + 1

print occurrence
```